# How can I escape a section of my page which contains multiple shortcodes?

Tags: shortcode

For testing purposes I often test multiple shortcodes on the same page and examine the results.  However I would like to display the short codes being tested.  There are a number of websites dealing with how to escape shortcodes one by one (just by doubling the "[") , more details below:

https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/escape-shortcodes-wordpress/

However I would like to escape a whole paragraph contianing multiple shortcodes.  Is there a plugin or shortcode to accomplish this?  ideally something like

[verbatim]
Complex paragraph containing [myshortcode1], [myshortcode2] which should not be expanded.
[endverbatim]

Comment: I am pretty certain that there is a default  "code" block in WordPress.